# Narrow a TypeScript union using an object with types mapped to React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'd like to use the following pattern to be able to render `ObjectForm` and pass either a `Foo` or a `Bar` and have that object's corresponding form rendered:

```
import React from 'react'

interface Foo {
    type: 'foo'
}

interface Bar {
    type: 'bar'
}

type ObjectTypes = Foo | Bar

const FooForm = ({ object }: { object: Foo }) => {
    return <form>I'm a form for foos</form>
}

const BarForm = ({ object }: { object: Bar }) => {
    return <form>I'm a form for bars</form>
}

const ObjectForm = ({ object }: { object: ObjectTypes }) => {
    const Form = {
        'foo': FooForm,
        'bar': BarForm
    }[object.type]
    
    // TypeScript complains here that `object`
    // can be either a `Foo` or a `Bar`. I'd like
    // to figure out how to narrow it to the correct
    // type.

    return <Form object={object} />
   
    // Using a switch works but seems very repetitive
    // for larger mappings. 

    // switch (object.type) {
    //     case "foo":
    //         return <FooForm object={object} />
    //     case "bar":
    //         return <BarForm object={object} />
    // }
}
```

Is there any way to narrow `object` to the correct type in my example without resorting to using the switch?

Alternatively, is there a better pattern to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to help the compiler understand the mapping:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#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)

```ts
type FormComponent<T, R extends ReactNode = ReactElement> = (props: { object: T }) => R;

const formComponentMap = {
  foo: FooForm,
  bar: BarForm,
} satisfies { [O in ObjectTypes as O["type"]]: FormComponent<O> };

const ObjectForm = <T extends ObjectTypes>(
  { object }: { object: T },
): ReactElement => {
  const Form = formComponentMap[object.type] as FormComponent<T>;
  return <Form object={object} />;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, with the assertion don't I lose type safety? I can change the `formComponentMap` so that the type `bar` is mapped to `FooForm` and this doesn't result in an error (like it would using the switch example) until runtime.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75935188/narrow-a-typescript-union-using-an-object-with-types-mapped-to-react-components/75935489?noredirect=1#comment133946103_75935489) @user1032752 Yes, that's true — you can use the [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) operator to constrain the `formComponentMap` object — which will prevent mistakes like the one you described (example: https://tsplay.dev/mA8J8N). I've updated the answer.