How to narrow type in a Hash Map/Dictionary of React Components?
I'm trying to narrow types without condition blocks, only using Hash Map/Dictionary.
I have components that accept mixed data shape's coming from the same data/source. These components handle some visual variations.
The data has a key (category) that indicates the right component to render the information.
Type and components (example):
enum Category {
  "Foo",
  "Bar"
}

type Card = {
  category: Category.Foo,
  message: string;
} | {
  category: Category.Bar,
  active: boolean;
}

const CardCategoryFoo = ({ data }: { data: Extract<Card, { category: Category.Foo }> }) => 
  <div>Foo: {data.message}</div>;

const CardCategoryBar = ({ data }: { data: Extract<Card, { category: Category.Bar }> }) => 
  <div>Bar: {data.active ? "Active" : "Inactive"}</div>;

Scenario narrowing with conditions (works):
// Scenario where narrow works
const Page1 = ({ data }: { data: Card }) => {
  if (data.category === Category.Foo) {
    return <CardCategoryFoo data={data} />;
  }

  if (data.category === Category.Bar) {
    return <CardCategoryBar data={data} />;
  }

  return null;
}

Scenario trying to narrow with hash map (doesn't work, but I really wanted to):
// Scenario where narrow doesn't work
const Page2 = ({ data }: { data: Card }) => {
  const cardDictionary = {
    [Category.Foo]: <CardCategoryFoo data={data} />,
                                  // ^ TypeScript Error
    [Category.Bar]: <CardCategoryBar data={data} />,
                                  // ^ TypeScript Error
  };

  return cardDictionary[data.category] ?? null;
}

TypeScript Playground: Link
Can I solve this with a simple solution still using Hash Map/Dictionary?
Alternatives?
After some research, I found that maybe this is not possible with a simple solution. One of these solutions is type assertion (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75935489/2154508). The thing is: I don't want to rely on as Something every time.
So, what is the best pattern to follow which cover all the cases?
Continue with if/else conditions? Jump right on switch cases?
What is the best recommendation in this scenario?

switch/case is indeed the most appropriate and straightforward solution here, also the most efficient one.
